# What would I alter to have the string word to give the same index for the uppercase letters as the lowercase letters?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
      obj.alphaSum("adam"); // I want to print "Adam" and get the same value
    }

public static void alphaSum(String word)

    {

        String alphabet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        int add = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)

        {

            char ch = word.charAt(i);

            int x = alphabet.indexOf(ch); 

            System.out.println(ch + " " + x);

            add+=x;
        }

        System.out.println("********************");
        System.out.println("Lucky Sum: " + add);

    }
```

The uppercase "A" provides a  -1 since the "A" is not listed in the String value. I want to know how I could incorperate the uppercase letters into this program.

I want to alter the code so that Adam with the uppercase "A" gives out the same index value as the lowercase "a" and give the same "Lucky Sum".

Comment: Simply use [String.toLowerCase()](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_tolowercase.asp).  EXAMPLE: `String w2 = word.toLowerCase(); for(int i = 0; i < w2.length(); i++) {...}`

Comment: How would I print the capital A since the lower case converts all of the inputted value as all lowercase.

Comment: Q: How would I print the capital A?  A: You *MAKE A COPY*.  Use the "all lower case" copy ("w2" in my example) for your count; print from the "original".  Which is pretty much EXACTLY what zelite tried to show you (we both happened to answer at the same time).  Please consider "upvoting" and "accepting" his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the input word to lowercase.

```
public static void alphaSum(String word)

    {
        String lowerCaseWord = word.toLowerCase();
        String alphabet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        int add = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < lowerCaseWord.length(); i++)

        {

            char ch = lowerCaseWord.charAt(i);

            int x = alphabet.indexOf(ch); 

            System.out.println(ch + " " + x);

            add+=x;
        }

        System.out.println("********************");
        System.out.println("Lucky Sum: " + add);

}
```